# Styling the last 5th li in my list

Tags: wordpress, css, html-lists

I'm running this website on wordpress and the list is generated by a plugin, however I can't seem to change anything any of the styling on the last li tag.

#### HTML

```
<div class="home">
    <p></p>
    <h4><li><a class="wp-super-faq-question-closed" id="wp-super-faq-question--0" href="http://www.statics-wanted.co.uk/statics4cash/?wp_super_faq=earn-an-extra-750-for-your-static-genuine-additional-bonus" title="…Earn an Extra £750* for your static, Genuine Additional Bonus!!!”" rel="question"><span class="wp-super-faq-triangle">▶</span> …Earn an Extra £750* for your static, Genuine Additional Bonus!!!”</a></li></h4>
    <div class="wp-super-faq-answer" id="wp-super-faq-question--0-answer" style="zoom: 1; display: none;">Enter answer here</div>
    <h4><li><a class="wp-super-faq-question-closed" id="wp-super-faq-question--1" href="http://www.statics-wanted.co.uk/statics4cash/?wp_super_faq=you-want-to-sell-your-static-fast-and-for-as-much-as-possible" title="“…You want to sell your static FAST and for as much as possible.”" rel="question"><span class="wp-super-faq-triangle">▶</span> “…You want to sell your static FAST and for as much as possible.”</a></li></h4>
    <div class="wp-super-faq-answer" id="wp-super-faq-question--1-answer" style="zoom: 1; display: none;">Enter answer here</div>
    <h4><li><a class="wp-super-faq-question-closed" id="wp-super-faq-question--2" href="http://www.statics-wanted.co.uk/statics4cash/?wp_super_faq=85-of-customers-received-more-money-by-using-us" title="“…85% of customers received more money by using us.”" rel="question"><span class="wp-super-faq-triangle">▶</span> “…85% of customers received more money by using us.”</a></li></h4>
    <div class="wp-super-faq-answer" id="wp-super-faq-question--2-answer" style="zoom: 1; display: none;">Enter answer here</div>
    <h4><li><a class="wp-super-faq-question-closed" id="wp-super-faq-question--3" href="http://www.statics-wanted.co.uk/statics4cash/?wp_super_faq=we-have-over-98-customer-satifaction" title="“…We have over 98% customer satifaction.”" rel="question"><span class="wp-super-faq-triangle">▶</span> “…We have over 98% customer satifaction.”</a></li></h4>
    <div class="wp-super-faq-answer" id="wp-super-faq-question--3-answer" style="zoom: 1; display: none;">Enter answer here</div>
    <h4><li><a class="wp-super-faq-question-closed" id="wp-super-faq-question--4" href="http://www.statics-wanted.co.uk/statics4cash/?wp_super_faq=last-year-we-spent-over-1million-buying-static-caravans" title="…Last year we spent over £1million buying Static Caravans" rel="question"><span class="wp-super-faq-triangle">▶</span> …Last year we spent over £1million buying Static Caravans</a></li></h4>
    <div class="wp-super-faq-answer" id="wp-super-faq-question--4-answer" style="zoom: 1; display: none;">Enter answer here</div>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.home li {
    list-style:url(../images/fact.png);
}
.home h4 li:nth-child(5) {
    padding-top:20px
}
```

**[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/7ky4z/1/)**

Many Thanks

Comment: Why do you put a `li` tag inside a `h4` tag? That's no valid HTML! When I validated your HTML in the W3C Validator, I got this error 5 times:
`Element li not allowed as child of element h4 in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)`
A `li` tag must be an element of a `ul` or `ol` list!

Comment: I understand, but this isn't the issue here please keep it on topic.

Comment: Your HTML is totally wrong and that's why your CSS is not working. `CSS Pseudo-classes` does not work on such HTML. It requires proper formatting like this http://jsfiddle.net/7ky4z/8/

P.S @ProgramFOX was on the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the li isn't the n'th child, they are each within a `<h4>` element. if you use :

```
.home h4:nth-child(10) li {padding-top: 20px;}
```

This should resolve the problem

Comment: Ohh thankyou, I'll try this out and accept your awnser if its correct.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a css class as

```
li.last-item { /* ... */ }
```

and apply it on your last list item.